# Firebase auth - Cannot read property '_getIdTokenResponse' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I'm unable to sign in to firebase with `GoogleProvider` due to `Cannot read property '_getIdTokenResponse' of undefined` error on expo + react native and [react-native-google-signin](https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin).

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";

// Libs
import { GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithCredential } from "firebase/auth";
import {
  GoogleSignin,
  GoogleSigninButton,
} from "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin";

// App

export default function GoogleAuth() {
  const [isInProgress, setInProgress] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    GoogleSignin.configure({
      webClientId: 'xyz',
      offlineAccess: true, // if you want to access Google API on behalf of the user FROM YOUR SERVER
      forceCodeForRefreshToken: true, // [Android] related to `serverAuthCode`, read the docs link below *.
      profileImageSize: 480, // [iOS] The desired height (and width) of the profile image. Defaults to 120px
    });
  }, []);

  async function signIn() {
    try {
      setInProgress(true);
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
      const { idToken } = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      setInProgress(false);
      return signInWithCredential(GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken));
    } catch (error) {
      //
      setInProgress(false);
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.button}>
        <GoogleSigninButton
          size={GoogleSigninButton.Size.Icon}
          color={GoogleSigninButton.Color.Light}
          onPress={signIn}
          disabled={isInProgress}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

```
"expo": "^49",
"react-native": "0.72.6",
"firebase": "^10.7.2",
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not be mixing use of `@react-native-google-signin/google-signin` and `firebase`.  If you are looking to leverage Google Sign In, consider going with [`react-native-firebase`](https://rnfirebase.io) and Firebase Authentication's GoogleAuthProvider.

It would not surprise me that the configuration you are using don't work together.  I'm going to guess that the `idToken` object of one is not designed to work with the other.